# Linked Lists in C, Random output?

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct list
{ 
    int data; 
    struct list *next;
}; 

struct list *start, *end; 
void add(struct list *head, struct list *list, int data); 
void delete(struct list *head, struct list *tail); 

int main(void)
{ 
    start=end=NULL; 
    add(start, end, NULL); 
    add(start, end, NULL); 
    printf("First element: %d"); 
    delete(start, end);
    return 0; 
} 

void add(struct list *head, struct list *tail, int data)
{ 
    if(tail==NULL)
    { 
        head=tail=malloc(sizeof(struct list)); 
        head->data=data; head->next=NULL; 
    } else { 
        tail->next=malloc(sizeof(struct list)); 
        tail=tail->next; 
        tail->data=data; 
        tail->next=NULL; 
    } 
}

void delete(struct list *head, struct list *tail)
{ 
    struct list *temp; 
    if(head==tail)
    {  
        free(head); 
        head=tail=NULL;
    } else { 
        temp=head->next; 
        free(head); 
        head=temp; 
    } 
}
```

I am aiming to return an output of 3 but keep getting random results.  Any insight is greatly appreciated

Comment: What results do you actually get? And why can't you just fix the poor formatting instead of apologizing?

Comment: Why not sort out the formatting before publishing it before the world? Would take about the same time as writing this post and **MAYBE** find a few errors? Just an idea that popped into my head. Also likely to get a better reply

Answer (score 2):

As you want to modify `head` and `tail` you need to pass a pointer to them.

i.e.

```
void add(struct list **head, struct list **tail, int data)
{ 
    if(*tail==NULL)
    { 
        *head = *tail = malloc(sizeof(struct list)); 
        (*head)->data = data;
        (*head)->next = NULL; 
    } else { 
        (*tail)->next = malloc(sizeof(struct list)); 
        *tail = (*tail)->next; 
        (*tail)->data = data; 
        (*tail)->next = NULL; 
    } 
}
```

Do similarly for the other function. Then head and tail will also change outside the function.

The line

```
printf("First element: %d");
```

It requires an integer to print - supply it - see the manual page for [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

Avoid using keywords for C++ in C programs - such as `delete`

Comment: Doesn't that need to be `(*head)->data` etc?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Yes - Oops - Need more coffee!.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters of C functions are passed by value. Thus, the changes that you make to the values of `head` and `tail` in the `add()` function will not be reflected in `main()` from which `add()` is called.

And, it doesn't seem that you've supplied a second parameter for `printf()`, so the `%d` format is not going to get the integer value that it will be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems here.

First, when you pass a pointer to a function, the pointer is passed by value. Any changes to the pointer in the called function will not be reflected in the calling function. To change what the pointer in the calling function is pointing to, you need to pass a pointer-to-pointer. So your `add()`function needs to be:

```
void add(struct list **head, struct list **tail, int data) { 
    if(*tail == NULL) { 
        *head = *tail = malloc(sizeof(struct list)); 
        (*head)->data = data; 
        (*head)->next = NULL; 
    } 
    else { 
        (*tail)->next = malloc(sizeof(struct list)); 
        (*tail) = (*tail)->next; 
        (*tail)->data = data; 
        (*tail)->next = NULL; 
    } 
    return;
}
```

And your `delete()` function needs to be changed similarly.

Secondly, you are passing NULL as your data value to the add function. NULL is a pointer; it is typically defined as a macro, and could be `(void*) 0` in the implementation. It should not be used as an integer. Pass `0` as the integer, not NULL.

Third, you have this statement:

```
printf("First element: %d");
```

Your format string has the conversion specifier `%d` but there is no argument that matches the `%d`. This is undefined behavior. What integer exactly are you trying to print?

Where do you expect the output `3`, and for what reason?

Answer (score 1):

In your program **start and end are global variables**, so there is no need to pass it as arguments to other functions, because other methods can directly access it.

```
 //Structure to store data
 struct list
 { 
    int data; 
    struct list *next;
 }; 

 // global variables
 struct list *start, *end; 
 void add(int); 
 void delete(); 

// start of program
int main(void)
{ 
    start=end=NULL;
    add(5); 
    add(6); 
    printf("\nFirst element: %d",start->data);    
    delete();
    printf("\nFirst element: %d",start->data); 
 return 0; 
} 

//add node to list
void add(int data)
{ 
    if(end==NULL)
    { 
        start=end=malloc(sizeof(struct list)); 
        start->data=data; start->next=NULL; 
    } else { 
        end->next=malloc(sizeof(struct list)); 
        end=end->next; 
        end->data=data; 
        end->next=NULL; 
    } 
}

// delete node from list
void delete()
{ 
    struct list *temp; 
    if(start==end)
    {  
        free(start); 
        start=end=NULL;
     } else { 
        temp=start->next; 
        free(start); 
        start=temp; 
     } 
}

OUTPUT:
   First element: 5
   First element: 6
```

**Note:**
If you don't want your start and end to be global than it can be a local variable of main function. Here you have to either work on double pointer mechanism or return memory address to retain the modification.

Comment: Yes, they're global variables, but they probably shouldn't be.  The code is more flexible if the head and tail are passed to the functions instead of being globals.  One might even argue for a structure to hold both head and tail to be passed as a pointer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree with you. Since OP's implementation was with global variables, i have just tweaked his code to work, so he may understand his mistakes.